# Position page number outside of text block (horizontally) using fancyhdr

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

Is there a way of positioning the page number outside (move it horizontally) of the text block using the `fancyhdr` package, as shown below?[image]

I have tried using `\hspace` to control the position of it but without any luck.

Please see the following MWE.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,openright]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{hmargin=1.5in,bmargin=1.5in,tmargin=1.5in,centering}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%% Page Styles
% Front Matter
\fancypagestyle{fancyFrontMatter}[fancy]{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
% Main Matter
\fancypagestyle{fancyMainMatter}[fancy]{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.75pt}}
% Reset plain style for chapter pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} % same placement as with page style "fancy"
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancyFrontMatter}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \pagestyle{fancyMainMatter}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place negative space to the outside edge:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{hmargin=1.5in,bmargin=1.5in,tmargin=1.5in,centering}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%%% Page Styles
% Front Matter
\fancypagestyle{fancyFrontMatter}[fancy]{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-1cm}\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage\hspace*{-1cm}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
% Main Matter
\fancypagestyle{fancyMainMatter}[fancy]{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-1cm}\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage\hspace*{-1cm}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.75pt}}
% Reset plain style for chapter pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\hspace*{-1cm}\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage\hspace*{-1cm}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancyFrontMatter}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \pagestyle{fancyMainMatter}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

note the measurement is to the outer edge of the number so the original 0pt would keep it inside the text block, unlike your red arrow if set to 0pt would imply the number is just outside the text block.